# Loop over array and compare to other array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create a code that will take a sentence as a param, split that sentence into an array of words and then  create a loop that checks if any of theses word matches a word in some other arrays.

In the example below, I have a sentence that contains the word "ski". This means that the return value should be `categories.type3`.

How can I have make the loop check this? Could I have a function switching between different categories ? (ie : if a word is not in `action`, look in `adventure` and so on).

```
var categories = {

    type1: "action",
    type2: "adventure",
    type3: "sport"
}

var Sentence = "This sentence contains the word ski";

var sport = ["soccer", "tennis", "Ski"];
var action = ["weapon", "explosions"];
var adventure = ["puzzle", "exploring"];

var myFreeFunc = function (Sentence) {

    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {

        if (typeArr[i] == word) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: a word may not be so obvious as you think. Is "mountain bike" a word ?

Comment: You are right of course. In this scenario "mountain" and "bike" are two different words.

Comment: have you considered using [regex](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info)?

Comment: Im not familiar with such a thing but I can have a look at it. Im a js-novice.

Comment: @Goodword if he did, he'd have two problems...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rewrite the code (you should always combine var statements).

I've added a small [fiddle snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/BananaAcid/4bpo16n3/), how i would rewrite the function. Just as an example, how you could iterate your data. Of course you should check out the other posts to optimise this code snipped ( e.g. fix for multiple spaces! ).

```
// make sure, your dictionary contains lower case words
var categories = {
    action: ["soccer", "tennis", "ski"],
    adventure: ["weapon", "explosions"],
    sport: ["puzzle", "exploring"]
}

var myFreeFunc = function myFreeFunc(Sentence) {

    // iterates over all keys on the categories object
    for (var key in categories) {

        // convert the sentence to lower case and split it on spaces
        var words = Sentence.toLowerCase().split(' ');

        // iterates the positions of the words-array            
        for (var wordIdx in words)
        {
            // output debug infos
            console.log('test:', words[wordIdx], categories[key], categories[key].indexOf(words[wordIdx]) != -1, '('+categories[key].indexOf(words[wordIdx])+')');

            // lets the array function 'indexOf' check for the word on position wordIdx in the words-array
            if (categories[key].indexOf(words[wordIdx]) != -1 ) {
                // output the found key
                console.log('found', key);

                // return the found key and stop searching by leaving the function
                return key;
            }

        }//-for words


    }//-for categories

    // nothing found while iterating categories with all words
    return null;
}
```

stripped down the function part snippet (no comments, no extra spaces, no console.log):

```
var myFreeFunc = function myFreeFunc(Sentence) {
    for (var key in categories) {
        var words = Sentence.toLowerCase().split(' ');          
        for (var wordIdx in words)
        {
            if (categories[key].indexOf(words[wordIdx]) != -1 ) {
                return key;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Accumulated the topics covered in the comments

- check if the Object really owns the property: [obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)
- split string by word bounds, as mentioned by Alnitak (using RegExp): /\b/g
- collecting categories for multiple matching

Snippet:

```
var myFreeFunc = function myFreeFunc(Sentence) {
    var result = []; // collection of results.
    for (var key in categories) {
        if (categories.hasOwnProperty(key)) { // check if it really is an owned key
            var words = Sentence.toLowerCase().split(/\b/g);  // splitting on word bounds        
            for (var wordIdx in words)
            {
                if (categories[key].indexOf(words[wordIdx]) != -1 ) {
                    result.push(key);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This one looks very nice and I can actually understand most of it =)

Comment: it's actually incorrect, though - it's using `for .. in` to iterate over an array.

Comment: also, what if more than one category is matched?

Comment: `var result = [];`  and in case of a return, do a `result.push(key);`, and at the end `return result;` .. but thats the usual - left to the reader - exercise. i actually removed it to make the code cleaner to read.

Comment: `for .. in`: objects may be addressed like arrays. obj[accessor] as well as obj.accessor - and sporting the same iteration interfaces. btw `for .. in` support is broader

Comment: I actually went with this solution. It worked out fine for me. 
I do not know if this solution is the best in terms of best practices etc..It seem that @Alnitak knows his buisness very well. But since this is the one that i used im gonna mark it as an answer.

Comment: @BananaAcid you still shouldn't use `for .. in` because it has the undesirable property (no pun intended) that enumerable properties added to either `Array.prototype` or `Object.prototype` (or even to the array itself) will appear.

Comment: @Alnitak that's true - should have mentioned it. I'll expand the post to include the things discussed.

Comment: @BananaAcid IMHO it would be better to simply replace the `for .. in` with a standard `for` loop...

Comment: @Alnitak i like using the cleaner syntax using `for .. in` :) well, that's what makes finding a good and clean way to code for **oneself** so interesting - JS is very flexible, requiring the scripter to understand a lot more of possible side effects - i'd say.

Answer (score 3):

You appear to want to know which categories match the sentence.

To start with, get rid of the meaningless `type1` etc identifiers and re-arrange your fixed data into objects that directly represent the required data, specifically a `Map` of key/value pairs, where each key is a "category" name, and each value is a `Set` of keywords associated with that category:

```
var categories = new Map([
    ['action', new Set(['weapon', 'explosions'])],
    ['adventure', new Set(['puzzle', 'exploring'])],
    ['sport', new Set(['soccer', 'tennis', 'ski'])]
]);
```

[NB: `Set` and `Map` are new ES6 features.  Polyfills are [available](https://github.com/Benvie/harmony-collections)]

You now have the ability to iterate over the `categories` map to get the list of categories, and over the contents of each category to find the key words:

```
function getCategories(sentence) {
    var result = new Set();
    var words = new Set(sentence.toLowerCase().split(/\b/g)); /* "/b" for word boundary */
    categories.forEach(function(wordset, category) {
        wordset.forEach(function(word) {
             if (words.has(word)) {
                 result.add(category);
             }
        });
    });
    return result.values();  // NB: Iterator interface
}
```

NB: I've avoided `for .. of` because it's not possible to polyfill that, whereas `Set.prototype.forEach` and `Map.prototype.forEach` can be.

Comment: This looks interesting and complete. I´ll have a go at this one too. Thank you

Comment: i like this ECMAScript 6 (Map and Set) approach - just make sure, the target environment supports it (as well as forEach and .has()).

Comment: yep, just empathising it :)

Comment: @BananaAcid ITYM "emphasising" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

One simple way would be to do like this :

```
function determineCategory(word){

    var dictionnary = {
       // I assume here you don't need category1 and such

        action: ["weapon", "explosions"],
        aventure: ["puzzle", "exploring"],
        sport: ["soccer", "tennis", "ski"]
    }
    var categories = Object.keys(dictionnary);
    for(var i = 0; i<categories.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j<categories[i].length;j++){
            var wordCompared = dictionnary[categories[i]][j];
            if(wordCompared == word){
                return categories[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return "not found"; 
}

var sentence = "This sentence contains the word ski";
var words = sentence.split(" "); // simple separation into words
var result = [];
for(var i=0; i<words.length; i++){
    result[i] = determineCategory(words[i]);
}
```

A few notes on this approach :

- it needs you to change your existing structure (I don't know if its possible)
- it doesn't do much for your sentence splitting (just using the white space). For more clever approach, see Alnitak's answer, or look for **tokenization**/**lemmatization** methods.
- it is up to you to determine what to do when a word doesn't belong to a category (right now, it just stores "not found".